# SR suffix on my ticket when not falling under the category

Tags: passports, tickets, international-travel

so I had to put a suffix on my delta ticket, and I put Sr, I'm 19 but did I do something wrong, since it doesn't show Sr on my passport.

I'm kind of scared I messed something up. I hope anyone can tell me if I did anything wrong or if it will be a problem that it says Sr on my ticket and not my passport/id

Comment: Why do you think you "had" to supply a suffix?

Comment: cause when i tried pressing next it said it needed a suffix, but do u think that, it will have any problems involved with it

Comment: They probably meant you need to select Mr./Mrs. Maybe bad translation.

Comment: yeah, im just curious if that could have any problems with me being able to board the plane if so

Comment: Same with me. SR after my last name. What did you do?. Should i correct it? The SR is not on my passport but on the flight ticket

Answer (score 3):

The reason the suffix exists on the form is to allow people like the actor Alec Baldwin (Alexander Rae Baldwin III) to book a ticket with his father (Alexander Rae Baldwin Jr). Two people with the same name on the same reservation confuses some systems and so airlines avoid it. If two people without any suffixes who do share a name book a single ticket then it's common practice for the airline to slam a jr suffix on the younger one so their system doesn't go bonkers.

Otherwise no one cares.

Comment: What happens if there’s two people born on the same day who share the same name? :)

Comment: On the same ticket?

Comment: Sure, why not? I imagine there's at least one pair of twins in the world named the same for some reason.

Comment: Ask someone with actual GDS access and insight. This is something Sabre at least used to have problems with, it being the oldest by far.